# Chef-Server Installation Ubuntu Error on execute[verify-system-status]

Tags: configuration, installation, ubuntu-12.04, chef-infra

I am trying to install chef-server on Ubuntu 12.04 following these instructions.

http://docs.opscode.com/install_server.html

My research has shown me that generally when this error shows it self it is because of the hostname

Here are my host settings:

```
root@dutches:/home/mrrc# cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       chef.dutches.com dutches localhost localhost.localdomain

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters


root@dutches:/home/mrrc# cat /etc/hostname
chef.dutches.com

root@dutches:/home/mrrc# hostname -f
chef.dutches.com

root@dutches:/home/mrrc# ping chef.dutches.com
PING chef.dutches.com (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from chef.dutches.com (127.0.0.1): icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=1.97 ms
64 bytes from chef.dutches.com (127.0.0.1): icmp_req=2 ttl=64 time=0.098 ms
64 bytes from chef.dutches.com (127.0.0.1): icmp_req=3 ttl=64 time=0.079 ms
64 bytes from chef.dutches.com (127.0.0.1): icmp_req=4 ttl=64 time=0.074 ms
^C
--- chef.dutches.com ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.074/0.557/1.979/0.821 ms
```

However when I try to configure chef I always get this error:

```
Recipe: chef-server::bootstrap
  * execute[verify-system-status] action run
================================================================================
Error executing action `run` on resource 'execute[verify-system-status]'
================================================================================


Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
------------------------------------
Expected process to exit with [0], but received '22'
---- Begin output of curl -sf http://127.0.0.1:8000/_status ----
STDOUT:
STDERR:
---- End output of curl -sf http://127.0.0.1:8000/_status ----
Ran curl -sf http://127.0.0.1:8000/_status returned 22


Resource Declaration:
---------------------
# In /opt/chef-server/embedded/cookbooks/chef-server/recipes/bootstrap.rb

 24: execute "verify-system-status" do
 25:   command "curl -sf #{erchef_status_url}"
 26:   retries 20
 27:   not_if { File.exists?(bootstrap_status_file) }
 28: end
 29:



Compiled Resource:
------------------
# Declared in /opt/chef-server/embedded/cookbooks/chef-server/recipes/bootstrap.rb:24:in `from_file'

execute("verify-system-status") do
  action "run"
  retries 0
  retry_delay 2
  guard_interpreter :default
  command "curl -sf http://127.0.0.1:8000/_status"
  backup 5
  returns 0
  cookbook_name :"chef-server"
  recipe_name "bootstrap"
  not_if { #code block }
end




Running handlers:
[2014-07-17T17:01:09-04:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
Running handlers complete

[2014-07-17T17:01:09-04:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2014-07-17T17:01:09-04:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /opt/chef-server/embedded/cookbooks/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
Chef Client failed. 10 resources updated in 70.5072942 seconds
[2014-07-17T17:01:09-04:00] ERROR: execute[verify-system-status] (chef-server::bootstrap line 24) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '22'
---- Begin output of curl -sf http://127.0.0.1:8000/_status ----
STDOUT:
STDERR:
---- End output of curl -sf http://127.0.0.1:8000/_status ----
Ran curl -sf http://127.0.0.1:8000/_status returned 22
[2014-07-17T17:01:10-04:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

Than I do:

```
root@dutches:/home/mrrc# curl http://127.0.0.1:8000/_status
{"status":"fail","upstreams":{"chef_solr":"fail","chef_sql":"pong"}}
```

Is it because I don't actually own the dutches.com domain? Even if my host file routes it locally? I want to access the server by IP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Chef Server installation **requires** a valid domain name (for a variety of reasons). You cannot access it by ip address.

Comment: Hmm.. ok thanks I will try this with a domain i own. Will accept the answer once it works.

Comment: I modified it to use a valid domain name. When I ping the domain from a different location it resolves to the correct IP address. However I am still getting the same error.

Comment: When I ping from within the server it pings to 127.0.0.1. Is this expected behaviour or should i modify the hosts file so it to ping to the public IP of the server?

Comment: After you change the domain name, you need to run `private-chef-ctl reconfigure`

Comment: The command is not found. Are you referring to chef-server-ctl reconfigure? Because I ran that and got the same error as in my original post.

Comment: I uninstalled chef server 11.1.3 and installed 11.0.8 and it worked. Not sure why but thanks.

Comment: i met same error. i removed proxy from environment then tried **chef-server-ctl reconfigure** it works.